# What is filling up var/log/asl files?

Tags: mac, macbook, asl

My mac is filling up my var/log/asl directory with .asl files repeating the same error and gradually decreasing my harddrive space at about a rate of 10 megs every minute or so. I get this repeated error, but can't figure out what it means.

```
Wed Apr  6 00:00:03 Bad-Horse tuxera_ntfs[50508] <Notice>: Error writing $Mft record(s): Device not configured
Wed Apr  6 00:00:03 Bad-Horse tuxera_ntfs[50508] <Notice>: MFT record sync failed, inode 16984: Device not configured
Wed Apr  6 00:00:03 Bad-Horse tuxera_ntfs[50508] <Notice>: Failed to free extent MFT record.  Leaving inconsistent metadata.
Wed Apr  6 00:00:03 Bad-Horse tuxera_ntfs[50508] <Notice>: ntfs_attr_mst_pwrite: written=-1: Device not configured
```

Does anyone know what this might refer to? It was suggested to me that it might be the time machine backup not finding a backup drive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the original author of the question.  I tried running chkdsk and it didn't help. However, I did find that when I took my USB drive and put it back on my PC and properly selected to "Safely remove hardware", it properly connected to my Mac without any problem and stopped the log messages.

Answer (score 4):

This seems to be a problem with [Tuxera NTFS](http://www.tuxera.com/products/tuxera-ntfs-for-mac/). It appears to be having a problem with one of your drives. Try unmounting and mounting it again, and if that doesn't help, check it with your favourite disk verification and repair software. Disk Utility won't cut it, unfortunately. Tuxera comes with `ntfsfix`, which can do some basic repairs, but the ultimate repair method is `chkdisk` on Windows.